# Python handling .net exceptions makes PyQt unable to use OLE

Tags: python, .net, qt, pyqt, python.net

I have a large PyQt4 based Python program. In some places it needs to be able to control a piece of hardware for which the manufacturer provides a .net interface. I need to be able to load the relevant library if it's available, and ignore it otherwise.

If the library is not present, and I try and report the exception, then Qt reports an OLE initialization error, and all drag-and-drop and copy/paste functionality in my program fails.

Here is a minimal example:

```
import clr
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

try:
    clr.AddReference('foo') #This doesn't exist
except Exception as e:
    logger.info('Exception: {0}'.format(e))
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
app.exec_()
```

This results in the Qt error:

```
Qt: Could not initialize OLE (error 80010106)
```

The program runs, but whenever I try and copy/paste, I get:

```
QClipboard::setMimeData: Failed to set data on clipboard ()
```

and drag-and-drop doesn't work at all.

If the library does exist, the code runs without a problem. Interestingly, if I don't try and look at the exception, (i.e. replace the except block with "pass"), the code also runs fine. Somehow, trying to see the exception messes up the .net interface.

Is there a better way to check whether a library exists before trying to add it as a reference? Is there any way to reset the .net connection before running QApplication, to guarantee that this sort of thing doesn't happen in the future? Any ideas why this problem happens?

Answer (score 2):

There is a better way than try to `clr.AddReference()` - the method is called `clr.FindAssembly('DOT_NET_Assembly_Name')` which returns full path to assembly or `None`.

Comment: Thanks, this is definitely a good suggestion. However, it doesn't really answer the question. Why does catching and printing an exception generated by trying to add a non-existent library cause an OLE initialization error?

Comment: it answers first of your 3 questions and solves the problem. the root cause is another story. did you file an issue on github?